# Cannot view .dae file in Xcode

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, maya

I export .dae file by Maya or 3dMax, copy this .dae file to xcode project, some time this file cannot view, I have to delete this file and export another file. 
When click on error file -> xcode show alert

> Unable to load
>   file:///Users/MACBOOK/Desktop/AR/TestAR%202/TestAR/TestAR/3d.scnassets/__testFile/model.dae.
>   (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The document "model.dae"
>   could not be opened."
>   UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/MACBOOK/Desktop/AR/TestAR%202/TestAR/TestAR/3d.scnassets/__testFile/model.dae,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The document "model.dae" could not be opened.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The document does not have a scene.
>   Please check that it has not been corrupted.})

Anyone know why this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using the default settings? are you exporting the entire scene? Can you please update the question with a screen-shot of your export settings from either  (or both) Maya or 3DS?

Comment: @tulip were you able to resolve this error?  Please post your solution if you have one.

Comment: @drewster , i work around, there is something you can try, export on mac or windown may be different, when export , give it a name different with current name.maya ..., then you can edit, don't export and replace file exist at the same time :)). Hope this help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered this issue, and I found this in the .dae file I was using:

```xml
<scene>
  <instance_visual_scene url="#walk test 3ds 2020 export"/>
</scene>
```

I removed the spaces to get

```xml
<scene>
  <instance_visual_scene url="#walktest3ds2020export"/>
</scene>
```

and also edited the other places that string appeared in the file, and it loaded successfully. So that is a possible thing to check.

See also this thread which is what prompted me to look for invalid characters: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fbx-forum/3d-artist/m-p/7294181/highlight/true#M8817

Comment: Mine had underscores instead of spaces, but resulted in the same issue. 
And don't forget to fix the `visual_scene`'s `id` key under the `library_visual_scenes` array.